# Relay to drive actuators

Tags: relay, actuator

wanting to use 240v AC motor controller to drive a DIY TV lift that uses DC actuators. The AC controller has Neutral, L1 and L2 outputs.

Will it work if I…

Wire 240v AC L1 and L2 outputs to each side of a relay coil
Wire 12v DC negative to NO side and negative side of actuator
Wire 12v DC positive to NC side and positive side of actuator

If so, any recommendations of the relay I should use or wiring advice appreciated.

12v DC at say 5A is required to drive the actuators.

Hope this makes sense. Not my bag really.

Thanks
D

Comment: the relay contacts are totally separate from the relay coil ... so your question is really about driving the relay coil ... what is connected to the contacts is irrelevant to the question

Comment: Attaching pictures & schematic would help to understand your question.

Comment: A TV lift would require only one motorised linear actuator working off a 240 V AC supply. What would be the purpose of the DC actuators?